# How to use trained model to get probability for each case in Keras

Tags: image, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I made image classification model and want to know the exact probability of each image before normalization

like

☆(star picture inputted)

-> {0.03, 0.07, 0.90} (result for {p_square, p_circle, p_star})

I have used

```
output_array=model.predict_classes(test_image)
```

it only print out one hot encoding value like

{1, 0, 0}

How to return prediction probabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call:

```
model.predict_proba(test_image)
```